# Can't force 'https' and reverse proxy with Apache at the same time

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy

Really racking my brain over this one. I need to always force 'https' whenever a user requests 'http' on my site, but at the same time I need to proxy pass from Apache to Tomcat (over http). I can't get these two pieces to work in tandem.

I have the https redirect defined here in httpd.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80> ServerName myserver.foo.com
    Redirect / https://myserver.foo.com/
</VirtualHost>
```

Then for the proxy:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteLog /opt/HTTPServer/logs/rewrite_log
RewriteLogLevel 9
RewriteRule ^/testnew/MyApp(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/test/MyApp$1?product=new  [NC,P,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/testold/MyApp(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/test/MyApp$1?product=old  [NC,P,QSA]
```

**Note:** This *does* actually work if I use ProxyPass instead, but I need to be able to add additional GET parameters to the request, hence the use of the [P] flag approach here.

So when I hit the following URL, I get the Apache HTTP Server page which reads "**Not Found**".
http://myserver.foo.com/testnew/MyApp/RunReport

In the access log, there's a 404

```
[10/Nov/2014:01:45:21 -0600] "GET /testnew/MyApp/RunReport HTTP/1.1" 404 321
```

Also, nothing gets written to the rewrite log.

As I understand it, RewriteRules will execute BEFORE Redirect, so even if the above URL did work (and I don't understand why it doesn't), it wouldn't get redirected from http to https.  So how can I accomplish this?

I also tried this using only RewriteRules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1  [R=301]

RewriteRule ^/testnew/MyApp(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/test/MyApp$1?product=new  [NC,P,QSA]
RewriteRule ^/testold/MyApp(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/test/MyApp$1?product=old  [NC,P,QSA]
```

However with this, the URL gets translated to include the https scheme and hostname after the 1st redirect, so the subsequent RewriteRules fail to match.  If I add the full 'https://myserver.foo.com' to the RewriteRule, it matches, but then the full URL gets translated back to http via the proxy.

I can't win!  This seems to me like it would be a fairly common configuration. Did I completely miss something?  I've been looking at this too long.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work by moving the proxy RewriteRules under the *:443 VirtualHost and leaving the http -> https ones at the global level, i.e.

```
Listen 443
<VirtualHost *:443>
    SSLEnable
    SSLClientAuth None
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteLog /opt/HTTPServer/logs/rewrite_log-443
    RewriteLogLevel 9

    RewriteRule ^/testnew/MyApp(.*)$  http://localhost:8080/test/MyApp$1?product=new [NC,P,QSA]

</VirtualHost>

...
...

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule ^(.*)$  https://%{HTTP_HOST}$1  [R=301]
```

Works beautifully now. :)